# При выводе окна не выводится картинка

Tags: c++, sfml

Вообщем использую библиотеку SFML(последнюю версию), и пытаюсь загрузить картинку,как бекграунд, но выходит только черный экран, в чем может быть проблема? Картинка находится в той же папке, что и программа.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Valentinka");

    sf::Image backimage;
    backimage.loadFromFile("background.png");

    sf::Texture backtexture;
    backtexture.loadFromImage(backimage);

    sf::Sprite backgroundSprite;
    backgroundSprite.setTexture(backtexture);
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(backgroundSprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Стоит начать с проверяния результата вызова `loadFromFile`.

Comment: @user7860670 Я так уже делал.В таком случае окно открывается на секунду, после чего сразу же закрывается

Comment: ¿Так а вызов `loadFromFile` при этом заканчивается успешно или нет? ¿На какой строке программа заканчивает работу?

Comment: @user7860670 На строке с проверкой, ошибка в том, что программа не может найти файл

Comment: Ну вот источник проблемы найден, теперь устраните его, указав правильный путь к файлу.